# SQL Server 2016 FOR JSON PATH returns string instead of array when using case statement

Tags: arrays, sql-server, json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to build a JSON object that contains an array, using SQL Server 2016.

The source data for the array is itself JSON, so I'm using the `JSON_QUERY` inside a select statement, with the FOR JSON clause applied to the select statement.

Everything works beautifully until I wrap the `JSON_QUERY` clause in a `CASE` statement (in certain cases the array must not be included, i.e. must be null).

The following code illustrates the problem:

```
declare  @projects nvarchar(max) = '{"projects": [23439658267415,166584258534050]}'
declare @id bigint = 123

SELECT 
      [data.array1] = JSON_QUERY(@projects, '$.projects') -- returns an array - perfect.
    , [data.array2] = CASE WHEN 1 is NOT NULL 
                           THEN JSON_QUERY(@projects, '$.projects') 
                           ELSE NULL END -- returns an array - still good!
    , [data.array3] = CASE WHEN @id is NOT NULL
                           THEN JSON_QUERY(@projects, '$.projects') 
                           ELSE NULL END  -- why do I end up with a string in the JSON when I do this?
FOR JSON PATH, without_array_wrapper
```

This code returns the following JSON:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "array1": [23439658267415,166584258534050],
      "array2": [23439658267415,166584258534050],
      "array3":"[23439658267415,166584258534050]"
   }
}
```

The problem is that the third 'array' is returned as a string object.

I would expect it to return the following JSON:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "array1": [23439658267415,166584258534050],
      "array2": [23439658267415,166584258534050],
      "array3": [23439658267415,166584258534050]
   }
}
```

If I remove the `FOR JSON PATH...` clause, all columns returned by the query are identical (i.e. all three nvarchar values returned by the `JSON_QUERY` function are identical).

Why is this happening, how do I make it output an array in the final JSON?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks @dfundako, I have edited the question to make it easier to understand and to include the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the result from the case statement in a call to `JSON_QUERY`.

```
, [data.array3] = JSON_QUERY(
                            CASE WHEN @id is NOT NULL
                            THEN JSON_QUERY(@projects, '$.projects') 
                            ELSE NULL END
                            )
```

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921884.aspx) JSON_QUERY "Extracts an object or an array from a JSON string". Further down it says "Returns a JSON fragment of type nvarchar(max).". A bit confusing.

Doing a `for xml json` on a string value will give you a string value in the returned JSON string and when you do it on a JSON object you get the JSON object inlined in the resulting string value.

You can look at CASE as a function call with a return value automatically determined for you by looking at what values you are returning from the CASE. And since JSON_QUERY returns a string the case will return a string and the returned value will be a string value in JSON.

The case statement in the query plan looks like this.

```
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="CASE WHEN [@id] IS NOT NULL THEN json_query([@projects],N'$.projects') ELSE NULL END">
```

When you wrap the case in a call to JSON_QUERY it looks like this instead.

```
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="json_query(CASE WHEN [@id] IS NOT NULL THEN json_query([@projects],N'$.projects') ELSE NULL END)">
  <Intrinsic FunctionName="json_query">
```

By some kind of internal magic SQL Server recognize this as a JSON object instead of a string and inserts it into the resulting JSON string as a JSON value instead.

`CASE WHEN 1 is NOT NULL` works because SQL Server is smart enough to see that the case statement will always be true and is optimized away.

Comment: Internal magic indeed: `select [a.b] = '[1,2]' for json path` returns a string in the JSON too - so even though the documentation says that JSON_QUERY returns a nvarchar(max), this is not quite strictly so - somehow "by internal magic" SQL server remembers that the object is an array, not a string..